# Headphones muted after startup

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Headphones always on mute after startup PC or killing pulseaudio by `pulseaudio -k`

It can be unmuted in alsamixer or in terminal `amixer set "Headphone" unmute`, but do this after each startup is annoying.
I created a script and added it to "Startup Applications", but it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
amixer set "Headphone" unmute
```

Also tried [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1430224&p=8969595#post8969595) and [this](https://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/ubuntu-12-04-dell-vostro-3750-no-sound-when-headphones-are-plugged-in/) guides, same result.
Headphones connected to Front Panel by 3.5 jack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To tell pulseaudio that headphones are always plugged in, edit the `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-lineout.conf` file.

Try to find the following lines in the file:

```
[Jack Headphone]
state.plugged = no
state.unplugged = unknown
```

And, if they exist, change `state.plugged = no` to `state.plugged = yes`.

Next, try find the following lines:

```
[Jack Front Headphone]
state.plugged = no
state.unplugged = unknown
```

Similarly, change `state.plugged = no` to `state.plugged = yes` if the lines exist.

Next, find these lines (if they exist):

```
[Element Headphone]
switch = off
volume = off
```

Change `switch = off` to `switch = on` here.

Also try to find these lines:

```
[Element Headphone2]
switch = off
volume = off
```

If they exist, change `switch = off` to `switch = on`.

**Save the file** and, finally, **restart pulseaudio**:

```
$ pulseaudio -k
$ pulseaudio --start
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case, i only had to change this
`[Element Headphone]
switch = off
volume = off`

Comment: Also you may want to change `volume = off` to `volume = merge` otherwise you won't hear anything because volumen will be at 0

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment Zé Bento's post.

What worked for me was changing both `Jack Headphone`'s and `Jack Front Headphone`'s `state.plugged` to `unknown`.

I don't know the meaning of that, but that was the default value for all other input types in my files.